# Implementing linked list on manipulating multiple list order with C++

Tags: c++

Disclaimer: This is homework and I am pretty much a complete beginner in programming (only took an intro class to C a few years ago). If it matters, this is from a Competitive Programming class. I appreciate all feedback besides on the question itself like good programming practices, naming conventions...etc. I am new to coding, but love it and want to improve.

> Consider *n* lists that are initialized with a single member that corresponds to its list number, i.e.:
>
> *#1: 1*
>   *#2: 2*
>   *#3: 3*
>   ...
>
> #### Input:
>
> First line contains *n m* where 1 ≤ *n* ≤ 1000000, 1 ≤ *m* ≤ 2000000;
>   Followed by *m* lines of *k a b*, where *k* is either 0 or 1 and denotes the type of manipulation:
>   *k* = 0: find **member** *a* and move from its position to behind **member** *b*
>   *k* = 1: move the **entire list** of *#a* list and place it behind the *#b* list
>
> #### Output:
>
> Print the lists in order after all the commands are executed. The question specifically states no whitespaces at the end of each line.

What I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class List {
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node *head;

public:
    List() {
        head = NULL;
    }

    Node *GetHead() {
        return head;
    }

    Node *GetPrevNode(int value) { // Gets the previous node to the node I am trying to move
        Node *temp, *peek;
        temp = head;
        peek = temp->next;

        if (head->data == value)
            return head;
        else {
            while (peek != NULL) {
                if (peek->data == value) {
                    return temp;
                }
                else {
                    temp = temp->next;
                    peek = temp->next;
                }
            }

            return NULL;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    Node *GetNode(int value) { // Gets the actual node I'm trying to move
        Node *temp;
        temp = head;

        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (temp->data == value) {
                return temp;
            }
            else {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    void PushNode(int value) {
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->data = value;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
        }
        else {
            head->next = temp;
        }
    }

    void MoveNode(Node *prevFrom, int value, Node *dest) { // called on the FROM list
        Node *tempDestNext, *from;
        tempDestNext = dest->next;
        if (prevFrom->data == value) {
            from = prevFrom;
        }
        else {
            from = prevFrom->next;
        }

        //different cases
        if (dest->next == from) {
            return;
        }
        else if (from->next == dest) {
            from->next = dest->next;
            dest->next = from;
            if (from == prevFrom) {
                head = dest;
            }
            else {
                prevFrom->next = dest;
            }
        }
        else {
            Node *tempFromNext;
            tempFromNext = from->next;
            dest->next = from;
            if (from == head) {
                head = tempFromNext;
            }
            else {
                prevFrom->next = tempFromNext;
            }
            from->next = tempDestNext;
        }
    }

    void ConcList(Node *headFrom) { // called on the DESTINATION list
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = headFrom;
        }
        else {
            Node *temp;
            temp = head;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                if (temp->next == NULL) {
                    temp->next = headFrom;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void PrintList() {
        Node *temp;
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << " " << temp->data;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
};

struct Move {
    int type, from, to;
};

void MarkNodePos(vector<int> &NodePos, int type, int from, int to) { // record on which list a node is
    switch (type) {
    case 0:
        NodePos[from - 1] = NodePos[to - 1];
        break;
    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < NodePos.size(); i++) {
            if (NodePos[i] == (from - 1)) {
                NodePos[i] = (to - 1);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

int RandomNum(int min, int max) {
    int range = max - min + 1;
    int num = rand() % range + min;
    return num;
}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0); // my teacher told us to include this code for speed optimization

    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    cin.ignore();

    vector<List> line;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        List temp;
        temp.PushNode(i + 1);
        line.push_back(temp);
    }

    vector<int> NodePos;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        NodePos.push_back(i);
    }

    string instrc;
    Move step;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {

        int mode = 0; // switch between input and testing mode

        switch (mode) {
        case 0: {
            getline(cin, instrc);
            stringstream ss(instrc);
            ss >> step.type >> step.from >> step.to;
            break;
        }

        case 1:
            stringstream ss;
            ss << RandomNum(0, 1) << " " << RandomNum(1, n) << " " << RandomNum(1, n);
            ss >> step.type >> step.from >> step.to;
            cout << step.type << " " << step.from << " " << step.to << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (step.from != step.to) {
            switch (step.type) {
            case 0:
                int from, to;
                from = NodePos[step.from - 1];
                to = NodePos[step.to - 1];
                line[from].MoveNode(line[from].GetPrevNode(step.from), step.from, line[to].GetNode(step.to));
                MarkNodePos(NodePos, step.type, step.from, step.to);
                break;
            case 1:
                if (line[step.from - 1].GetHead() != NULL) {
                    line[step.to - 1].ConcList(line[step.from - 1].GetHead());
                    List clear;
                    line[step.from - 1] = clear;
                    MarkNodePos(NodePos, step.type, step.from, step.to);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "#" << (i + 1) << ":";
        line[i].PrintList();
        if (i != (n - 1))
            cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

An example:

> Input:
>
> 6 4
>   0 4 3
>   0 6 5
>   1 2 5
>   1 6 5
>
> Output:
>
> *#1: 1*
>   *#2:*
>   *#3: 3 4*
>   *#4:*
>   *#5: 5 6 2*
>   *#6:*

I keep getting wrong answer from the judge but as you can seen, I used a random number generator to test out my program and from my testing it all seems fine. I really have no clue what to look for. What could be causing the error?

Comment: What is the actual output you are getting? Did you ask the judge why the output is wrong?

Comment: If this is C++, why are you not using `std::forward_list` instead of writing your own singly-linked list?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added an example of input/output. Please take a look - thank you! I did ask and the judge (my teacher, really) told me he can't show me the test content, that "you're not supposed to be able to see it" in competitive programming

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am using linked list because the teacher wants us to use this question to practice linked list, but I was not aware of std::forward_list. I will look into it, thank you!

Comment: whatever output you posted that one is correct one?

Comment: @MausamSinha Yes, that is correct and a reference given by the question. My program produces that output and other similarly correct outputs (granted, I can only test a reasonably small amount of data that is still possible for me to track).

Comment: @AlexCheng what is the use of n in your program

Comment: @MausamSinha n is used in the first line of input to specify how many initial lists there are to begin with (what I was talking about in the second paragraph: Consider n lists that are...)